# UWP Cortana not registering app commands

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, cortana

I am trying to implement Cortana to my app so when the user says "Hey Cortana, in test app read step one" the app will read the first element from a listbox. The problem I am having is that when I say this, the app just opens up a bing web page with the sentence I say.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.1">
<CommandSet xml:lang="en-US" Name="CommandSet_en-US">
<CommandPrefix> Test App</CommandPrefix>
<Example> read step one </Example>

<Command Name="step">
  <Example> read step one </Example>
  <ListenFor> read step {number} </ListenFor>
  <Feedback> Reading Instruction </Feedback>
  <Navigate Target="Page1"/>
</Command>

<PhraseList Label= "number">
  <Item> one </Item>
  <Item> two </Item>
</PhraseList>
</CommandSet>  
</VoiceCommands>
```

In app.xaml.cs:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
   //code
        Window.Current.Activate();
        }
            try
            {
                StorageFile vcdStorageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync( @"CortanaCommands.xml");
                await VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcdStorageFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There was an error Registering the Voice Command Definitions", ex);
            }
  }


  protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Kind != Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
        {
            return;
        }

        var commandArgs = e as Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs;
        var speechRecognitionResult = commandArgs.Result;
        string voiceCommandName = speechRecognitionResult.RulePath[0];
        string textSpoken = speechRecognitionResult.Text;

        string spokenStep = "";
        try
        {
            spokenStep = speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties["number"][0];
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        MainPage page = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
        if (page == null)
        {
            return;
        }


            switch (spokenStep)
            {
                case "one":                     
                    page.Count1 = 0;
                    break;

                default:
                    //no match
                    break;
            }

        switch (voiceCommandName)
        {
            case "step":
                page.StepOne();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your code, you catch the exception if there is an error Registering the Voice Command Definitions, are you sure you have registered your vcd file successfully? Your code works fine by my side, cortana will launch the app for a short time then close it, because you miss a `Window.Current.Activate();` in the end of your `OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)` method, or do you intend to do this?

Comment: Hi I managed to get Cortana to actually recognise the app, however when it gets to the line page.StepOne() the app crashes as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The page value is null however the type is App2.Page1.

Comment: By my side, the page value is `MainPage` while it is `Page1` by your side, but forget this, in your code, if `page` is null, it will return, this error should not occur. The problem is actually with your StepOne() method of your `App2.Page1`, and I've kind of test this method with no code in it, this error still doesn't occur by my side, please post the code of this method.

Comment: In the step one method I am trying to read the first value of a listbox that is in this page.  public void StepOne(int count1)
        {
            readText(SteplistBox.Items[count1].ToString());
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your problem, your `StepOne` method is like this:

```
public void StepOne(int count1) { readText(SteplistBox.Items[count1].ToString()); }
```

There is an argument in this method, but you call this method like this: `page.StepOne();` there is no arguments in this method. Please notice that `StepOne()` method and `StepOne(int i)` are two different methods.

Possible this problem is a typo, but I assume what you want to do is using cortana to open your app and reading items of `ListBox` from the `MainPage` according to the voice command. Plus the possible problems in my comments, here I wrote a sample for you:

App.xaml.cs code:

```
private string count = null;
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
    {
        VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs vargs = (VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs)args;
        SpeechRecognitionResult res = vargs.Result;
        string cmdName = res.RulePath[0];

        if (cmdName == "step")
        {
            var interpretation = res.SemanticInterpretation;
            string item = interpretation.Properties["number"].FirstOrDefault();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
            {
                Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                if (rootFrame == null)
                {
                    rootFrame = new Frame();
                    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
                }
                switch (item)
                {
                    case "one":
                        count = "one";
                        break;

                    case "two":
                        count = "two";
                        break;

                    default:
                        count = null;
                        break;
                }
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), count);
            }
        }
    }
    count = null;
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

MainPage.cs code:

```
public void StepOne(int i)
{
    readText(SteplistBox.Items[i].ToString());
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        if ((string)e.Parameter == "one")
        {
            StepOne(0);
        }
        else if ((string)e.Parameter == "two")
        {
            StepOne(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you don't want to use `OnNavigatedTo` method and `e.Patameter` of the Mainpage, you can change the code in the App.xaml.cs like this:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
 if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
 {
     VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs vargs = (VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs)args;
     SpeechRecognitionResult res = vargs.Result;
     string cmdName = res.RulePath[0];

     if (cmdName == "step")
     {
         var interpretation = res.SemanticInterpretation;
         string item = interpretation.Properties["number"].FirstOrDefault();
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
         {
             Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
             if (rootFrame == null)
             {
                 rootFrame = new Frame();
                 Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
             }
             rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
             MainPage page = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
             switch (item)
             {
                 case "one":
                     page.StepOne(0);
                     break;

                 case "two":
                     page.StepOne(1);
                     break;

                 default:
                     break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
 Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

And keep the `StepOne(int i)` method in the MainPage.cs like this:

```
public void StepOne(int i)
{
    readText(SteplistBox.Items[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, whilst this would normally work I am already using the onNavigatedTo method to retrieve the data for the listbox from a sqlite database so when I try to implement this, the app will crash in trying to use e.Parameter for the other instance I use it. Hopefully my problem is clear and there is a way to do this.

Comment: @myf33tsmell, It's easy to change my code to use no e.Parameter...Please see my update code.

Comment: thanks I tried this in another app and it works but this helped me figure the problem with my app. In my app to navigate to the mainpage I use:        var user = e.ClickedItem as SQLTable;
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), user.ID.ToString());                              So when I try to use cortana it navigates to an empty mainpage and not one with the sql information passed on to populate the listbox. Im not sure this can be sorted but it still helped a lot.